# How can i detect if a callback is triggered in pytorch?

Tags: python, nlp, pytorch, bert-language-model

I am fine-tuning a BERT model. First, I want to freeze layers and train a bit. When a certain callback is triggered (let's say `ReduceLROnPlateau`) I want to unfreeze layers. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid learning rate schedulers in PyTorch don't provide hooks. Looking at the implementation of [`ReduceLROnPlateau`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/optim.html#torch.optim.lr_scheduler.ReduceLROnPlateau) [here](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/d5a2429c241555ec70c1de522b74b9d173f97691/torch/optim/lr_scheduler.py#L641), two properties are reset when the scheduler is triggered (`i.e.` when it identifies a plateau and reduces the learning rate):

```
    if self.num_bad_epochs > self.patience:
        self._reduce_lr(epoch)
        self.cooldown_counter = self.cooldown
        self.num_bad_epochs = 0
```

Based on that, you could wrap your scheduler step call and find out if `_reduce_lr` was triggered by checking that both `scheduler.cooldown_counter == scheduler.cooldown` and `scheduler.num_bad_epochs == 0` are true.

Comment: Thank you. Actually it looks like i did not have to do such a thing. I can just check num_bad_epochs whether it is equal to patience i want.